# MYSQL Insert a same row to all members

Tags: mysql, count, sql-insert

i am here to ask for help, my problem is that i need to insert a same row into table for all members.

however, the `customer_id` id `members` from the table is duplicated:
[image]

i googled and find the way to sort the `customer_id` by not repeating:

```
SELECT * FROM `members` GROUP BY `customer_id` HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

but i don't know how to insert a same row into table by those `customer_id` list i have filted

for example:

```
INSERT INTO `members` (`customer_id`,`order_id`,`description`,`amount`) VALUES ('41624',0,'add same value example',100);

INSERT INTO `members` (`customer_id`,`order_id`,`description`,`amount`) VALUES ('41625',0,'add same value example',100);

INSERT INTO `members` (`customer_id`,`order_id`,`description`,`amount`) VALUES ('41626',0,'add same value example',100);

INSERT INTO `members` (`customer_id`,`order_id`,`description`,`amount`) VALUES ('41627',0,'add same value example',100);
```

etc...

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do. Would you show us what you want your table to contain?

Comment: @Schwern sorry for my poor eng.  i need to insert new row for all customers(coustomer_id), but there has 2 problems: 1) the table has show duplicated dcustomer_id like '41624'. 2) could i multi insert rows into the table by customer_id which not duplicated ?

Comment: *```SELECT * FROM `members` GROUP BY `customer_id` HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;```* 1) This query selects (not inserts) only those rows which have unique `customer_id` value over the table. 2) The query is incorrect, it uses incomplete grouping. Enabling `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL Mode will cause this query fall.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT DISTINCT
       customer_id, @value1, @value2, ...
FROM mytable
```

`SELECT DISTINCT customer_id ... FROM mytable` selects only one copy for each unique `customer_id` value which is present in the table, and `@value1, @value2` are literal values which must be placed into according columns in newly inserted rows.

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a4Vwh_eu)